# How do you change the target machine configuration in fortran?

Tags: fortran, cross-compiling

I am using the Intel Fortran Compiler on Linux. I know that if I type in "ifort -dumpmachine" it will provide the target machine configuration for the compilation (e.g. "x86_64-linux-gnu") but I need to know how to change this if I want to compile for a different operating system (e.g. a different version of linux). The "-arch" compiler option allows you to chagne the processor architecture but I need to know how to also change the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

Cross compilation is highly processor dependent stuff, so there is no general Fortran answer. As far as I know Intel Fortran is available only for a limited number of architectures - x86 and x86-64. There are separate products for Linux, Windows and OS X and you can not cross-compile between them.

You did not specify what you mean by different version of Linux. You should find in the manual of your version of the compiler, what kernel version need the resulting executables. In principle you can then target all such distributions. There may be also problems with the right Intel runtime libraries and glibc and also your other libraries you use. You can solve this by statically linking your libraries on your machine (use `-static`, or `-static-intel` for Intel runtime libraries only), but be aware, that they have to be also compatible with your target architecture (In particular, if they require advanced instruction set, like SSE(2) or AVX).